# Error Apache "[proxy_fcgi:error] (70007)The timeout specified has expired AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade)"

Tags: php, apache, symfony, fpm

I have a Symfony application under server Ubuntu with Apache 2.4 y PHP 7.4, but when i try upload big files, the Apache log show the next error:

```
[Tue Aug 16 19:06:24.155754 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 46311:tid 139679500326656] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 200.111.269.150:53464] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade), referer: http://147.182.242.247/2022-08-02/new-informe
```

Config apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# ...
DocumentRoot /var/www/informe-cajas/public

RequestReadTimeout handshake=0 header=20-600,MinRate=50 body=20,MinRate=50

Timeout 1200
ProxyTimeout 1200

#ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.php.*)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/<docroot>/$1 timeout=1800

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
</FilesMatch>

<Directory /var/www/informe-cajas/public>
    AllowOverride All

</Directory>
```

This error is frequently on someone places with slow velocity of internet

Sorry for my english!